# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at HomePage.webpackJsonp

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Here the video i am following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPOF_DJJeF0&list=PLYxzS__5yYQng-XnJhB21Jc7NW1OIaqct&index=9), I did same as video, but still showing me error undefined value. anyone had idea what to do. Please help me and i am using ionic 3,

Here the video i am following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPOF_DJJeF0&list=PLYxzS__5yYQng-XnJhB21Jc7NW1OIaqct&index=9), I did same as video, but still showing me error undefined value. anyone had idea what to do. Please help me and i am using ionic 3,
home.html

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
   <ion-item>
     <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="text" name="username" ></ion-input>
   </ion-item>

   <ion-item>
     <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="password" name="password"></ion-input>
   </ion-item>
 </ion-list>

     <div padding>
       <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="signIn()" block>Sign In</button>
     </div>

</ion-content>
```

home.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController  } from 'ionic-angular';

 @Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
 })
export class HomePage {
   @ViewChild('username') uname;
   @ViewChild('passwoed') password;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: 
  AlertController ) {

  }

signIn() {
console.log(this.uname.value, this.password.value)
    if(this.uname.value == "admin" && this.password.value == "admin") {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Login Successfull!',
          subTitle: 'You are logged in!',
          buttons: ['OK']
        });
        alert.present();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: i already solve your problem..

Comment: Hlw @user9088454 check your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You got mistake on `home.html`, i resolve this.**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" #username ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" #password></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

  <div padding>
    <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="signIn()" block>Sign In</button>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```